# iOS Swift: How to dismiss keyboard before compute-intensive code?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode9

I have a view with a textfield that the user will enter an integer with numeric keypad.

The user then clicks a button to calculate.

The calculation is CPU-intensive and takes several seconds or longer to complete depending on input.

If I try to dismiss keyboard before the code is run, it doesn't get dismissed--the code is run 1st. (example code below)

Is a background thread for this code required for the keyboard dismissal to work?

```
@IBOutlet weak var numberField: UITextField!

@IBAction func runCPUIntensiveCode(_ sender: UIButton) {
    numberField.resignFirstResponder()
    runCode()
}
```

Comment: Seems to work for me.
Do you have multiple textfields?

Comment: Bunch of labels, but just 1 text field. You wrote code that takes several seconds to finish?

Comment: No but the keyboard should get dismissed first. Does the keyboard get dismissed after your code is run?

Comment: @NSAdi Yes, it does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have a couple solutions with [`DispatchQueue`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatchqueue):
 1. [I recommend this] Move your calculations to background via one of [global background queues](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatchqueue/2300077-global):

```
@IBAction func runCPUIntensiveCode(_ sender: UIButton) {
    numberField.resignFirstResponder()
    DispatchQueue.global(.userInitiated).async{

      runCode()
    DispatchQueue.main.async{
      <notify UI about completion>
   }
}
```

2. Start calculation with small delay. Sometimes animation subsystem needs free main thread to schedule animation:

```
@IBAction func runCPUIntensiveCode(_ sender: UIButton) {
    numberField.resignFirstResponder()
    DispatchQueue.main. asyncAfter(DispatchWallTime.distantFuture){
      runCode()
      <notify UI about completion>
   }
}
```

Comment: Ok. Was planning on moving the code to background to show a spinner anyway. Just asked to clarify that threading is needed in this case.

Comment: You can select appropriated queue, based on your task. Think about quality of service (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatchqos) and select appropriated queue.

Comment: Used .utility QOS with DispatchWorkItem in this case. All set :-]